# React correctly fills useState value, then resets it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**tldr; Component correctly loads data with help of a HOC, but that data appears to be an empty array later when it needs to be updated.**

I have a *MyTablePage*, a *MyTable*, and a *withNetworking* Component.

The *withNetworking* code is intended to provide REST services in a HOC style (I don't fully understand HOC, so apologies if I'm using it incorrectly here -- React as a whole isn't exactly my usual programming environment).

```
return <div>
            <Component {...props} componentData={retrievedData ? retrievedData : defaultFetchResult} />
        </div>
```

*MyTable* is the gist of the code I'm writing, and provides a table with data loaded via *withNetworking* when the *MyTableWithData* (see *MyTablePage*, next) is loaded. It also provides a couple of buttons per row that make REST calls to manipulate the data on the backend and then update the UI accordingly.

```
// Table is an antd table, for the curious
return (
        <Table
            size="middle"
            scroll={{x: 1500}}
            dataSource={tableData ? tableData : []}
            columns={tableColumns}
            sticky
        />
    );
```

*MyTablePage* creates a *MyTableWithData* component:

```
    const MyTableWithData = withNetworking(MyTable, myDataTableProps);

    ....

    <MyTableWithData
        onB1Press={onB1Click}
     />
```

When the *MyTable* array Component mounts, I see the that the values **do get set properly**, based on data loaded through withNetworking. Both console logs here, in the following code, end up with 11 records provided from the backend service. Not sure which one should be in the watch array parameter, so I have both for now.

```
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        (() => {
            setTableData(componentData);
            console.log('COMPONENTData',componentData);
            console.log('TABLEData',tableData);
        })();
    }, [componentData, tableData]);
//COMPONENTData (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] MyTable.js:25
//TABLEData [] MyTable.js:26
//COMPONENTData (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] MyTable.js:25
//TABLEData (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]  MyTable.js:26
```

Clicking one of the buttons starts with a useCallback function defined in *MyTable*, which immediately calls onB1Click (defined in *MyTablePage*) to do some additional manipulation of the raw data returned from the server, so that the *MyTable* Component doesn't need to know the details of the raw data, itself. That detail is left to the *MyTablePage* onB1Click code.

Console logs show that onB1Click correctly returns the expected object to the button handler inside *MyTable*. At this point, I would like to update my data and see it reflected in my UI. *The problem is that my state value, **tableData** (as well as **componentData**), in *MyTable* is now logging as an empty array from within my button press handler*.

Now, I suspect that I will, in the future, have a problem in that manipulating the array won't necessarily force the Component(s) to update. I accept that as my next item to work out. But I am not ready to address that until I can discover why my state value has returned to an empty array, which clearly is not what I'm expecting.

Comment: `setTableData`, a setState function, is asynchronous. You cannot log the state immediately below a setState call. If you want to read the most updated version of the state you want to use an effect that use `tableData` as a dependency. You are already doing this, but in the first instance of the call the tableData is empty due to this synchronicity quirk. The second time the effect is called you get the updated data because tableData is already used as a dependency in this effect.